# Python not finding item in list

Tags: python-3.x

I am just trying out some basic functionality in Python, and this is the entire script that I wrote:

```
a = [5, 3, 6, 9, 7, 8]
x = input()
print(x in a)
```

This is always printing "False," even when the number that I input is in list a.  I don't know if this relevant, but I wrote the script in Notepad++ and I'm running it in the command prompt.  For example:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:\Users\ ... \Project.py
9
False

C:\Python34\python.exe C:\Users\ ... \Project.py
6
False
```

That makes no sense to me.  I don't understand what I did wrong.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3.x, the function `input()` returns a *string*. Since the list `a` contains *integers*, you have to convert the input to `int`:

```
x = int(input())
```

Comment: @user3504867 No problem. And... don't say that you are stupid (not even kidding).

Answer (score 1):

Cast the input to `int`. `input()` always returns a `string`

```
x = int(input())
```